# Java 8 Timezone conversion when creating java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, java-8

My local server is running in the eastern timezone and I would like to save the date a user enters in UTC. So I have a method that does the conversion

```
 public static Date getDate(LocalDateTime date, int timeZoneOffset) {
     OffsetDateTime dt = date.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(timeZoneOffset));
     System.out.println(dt);
     Instant instant = dt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC.toString())).toInstant();
     System.out.println(instant);
     Date d = new Date(instant.toEpochMilli());
     System.out.println(d);
     return d;
}
```

But the print out is this now:

> 2015-09-21T21:55-04:00 <- this is correct. input time with timezone offset EST
>
> 2015-09-22T01:55:00Z <- this is correct. input time in UTC
>
> Mon Sep 21 21:55:00 EDT 2015 <- this is wrong cause it now reverted my UTC time back to EST/EDT time

Why is that? And how can I get the `java.util.Date` object from the UTC time?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: A `Date` doesn't have a timezone.

Comment: I know that but the print out says EDT and when i check the database its saved in EDT and not UTC

Comment: Why are you printing out its `toString` value? Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format it with the appropriate timezone.

Comment: Well i am trying to figure out why in the db its saved as eastern timezone and not utc

Comment: Is it stored as a timestamp or as a string?

Comment: If you are using datetimes, MySQL has no knowledge of time zones. It assumes its system's.

Comment: System timezone is utc

Comment: Its a db in the cloud